# Unity displaying a texture's alpha channel incorrectly

Tags: image, blender

I've been troubleshooting a shader for quite some time now, and just now decided to have a closer look at the texture I'm using. And there seems to be quite a difference in how I expected the textures to look like (based on how the renders looked in blender) and how unity displays them (it looks the same when sampling it with a shader btw, so it's propably not related to the preview window). The right part of the screenshot also shows both import and export settings for the image.

[image: import and export settings]

Is there some kind of color correction going on here? How could I handle that and get unity to show the original image?

**EDIT:**

So I've done a lot of testing now and here's some of the stuff I've gotten to know so far:

The color channels blanking out seem to be a bug within unity. This only occurs when all 4 channels have the same values and does not affect the alpha channel. There's also no issue when having only 3 identical color channels (an rgb image).
[image: all alpha]

The change in brightness was caused by blender as well. The values displayed by unity seem to be correct, as verified by a third party webside:
[image: extracted]

Blender also showed the correct brightness after changing the view transform to raw:
[image: sdtvt]
[image: rawvt]

So hopefully these thing are cleared up now, the issue definetely is within blender (or propably more so in how I use it). But that

I am however still experiencing the artifacts I was earlier. You can see here how the red channel (now with some other information) looks before saving:
[image: bs]
And here how it does right after loading the saved image into the compositor back again. It seems like what I was blaming on compression earlier is caused by the alpha channel somehow being overlayed onto all the other ones:
[image: as]

All the channels look fine before saving the image (still to a simple rgba 64 bit png), so any help would still be appreciated. Would be glad to know if there's any further information I should provide as well.

Comment: It's possible that it's not an sRGB texture, try unchecking that box in the import settings (3rd setting from top in your screenshot). If this doesn't work, make sure to check the box again (if it is an sRGB texture, the colors would be messed up).

Comment: Thanks first of all, it really seems to be something in that area. But unfortunately, I saw no change when unchecking the sRGB box you suggested

Comment: Can you open the image in a 3rd software (e.g. default photos app) and check how it looks there? This would determine whether it's a problem with Blender or with Unity.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I extracted a single channel using a website (don't have a program to do that), and according to it, what unity is showing is indeed correct. I've edited the question now

Comment: In the last screenshot, maybe your preview uses black as the background (so transparency renders as black). In Unity try setting `Alpha Is Transparency` on the texture and using the Standard shader with `Fade` mode. I do not know what a "compositor" is, sorry if I misunderstood.